# pass complex parameters in http get method

Tags: java, http, xmlhttprequest

i what to pass parameters in http get method like

```
region:[{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.991466},{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.991466}]]
```

like:`http://127.0.0.1:8080//manage/vehicle/searchCircularArea/?region=`

i know `center:[116.300319,39.988877]` is like the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080//manage/vehicle/searchCircularArea/?center=116.300319&center=39.988877&radius=281
```

but how i write the url parameter of region?

thanks your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the correct way to encode/serialize this in an URL would be:

```
http://localhost:8000/manage/vehicle/searchCircularArea/?region[0][lng]=116.298871&region[0][lat]=39.991466
    &region[1][lng]=116.298871&region[1][lat]=39.990079
    &region[2][lng]=116.295787&region[2][lat]=39.990079
    &region[3][lng]=116.295787&region[3][lat]=39.991466
```

(Linebreaks included for the sake of legibility, "." should actually read "%2E")

Of course nothing can keep you from tossing JSON into the URL. But if you want something RFC-proof, it's the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a my solution.

```
region:[{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.991466},{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.991466}]
```

Maybe You can send the region like:

```
http://localhost:8080//manage/vehicle/searchCircularArea/?region="[{'lng':116.298871,    'lat':39.991466},{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.991466}]"
```

In the server you can use Jackson or Gson or other you like to transform the json string to a object.

Maybe:

```
class Loc {
     private double lng;
     private double lat;
     getter and setter;
}
class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          String region = "[{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.991466},{'lng':116.298871, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.990079},{'lng':116.295787, 'lat':39.991466}]";
          List<Loc> res = new Gson().fromjson(region), new TypeToken<List<Loc>>(){}.getType());
     }
}
```